# Finding a Basis for the Vector space of sequences of the form $u_{n+1} = u _{n-1} + u_n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, hamel-basis

The question asks to show that the set of real sequences $u_n$ satisfying the recurrence $u_{n+1} = u_n + u_{n-1}$ is a subspace of the space of all real sequences and then to find its basis.

To show that the set is a subspace I used the subspace test, but I had a problem finding the basis.

Here's how far I have got:

Any $u_n$ satisfying the recurrence $u_{n+1} = u_n + u_{n-1}$ could be expressed as a linear combination of $u_0$ and $u_1$
$$u_n = \lambda u_0 + \mu u_1$$
so to find the basis for this subspace, all we need to do is find the basis of $R^2$, which is $(1,0), (0,1)$.

Is that the right way to approach the question?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, it's interesting.  You are correct that the vector space in question is two dimensional, and as an abstract matter it is true that the initial conditions do define the series uniquely. Still, I expect that they are looking for closed form versions for the series.  For example, the functions $2^n, 3^n$ span the solutions to $a_n=5a_{n-1}-6a_{n-2}$.

Comment: @lulu then do I just solve the recurrence relation $u_{n+1} = u_n + u_{n-1}$ and say that the basis depends on the initial conditions?

Comment: The basis does not depend on the initial conditions.  In my example, the basis was $2^n, 3^n$.  The specific solution to the recursion does, of course, depend on the initial conditions.

Comment: Was my objection clear?  You can certainly defend the answer you gave...but I expect they are looking for the space as a subspace of functions on $\mathbb N$.  For instance, your solution works equally well for my example and yours.

Comment: Another basis is $a_n = \phi_+^n$ and $b_n = \phi_-^n$, where $\phi_+ = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\phi_- = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$ are the roots of $x^2 - x - 1 = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is correct. You have proved that your vector space is spanned by the Fibonacci sequence $0,1,1,2,3,5,8,\ldots$ and by a similar one: $1,0,1,1,2,3,5,\ldots$ Since they are linearly independent, your space has dimension $2$, and these two sequences form a basis of it.

Comment: It is pointed out [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3546037/fibonacci-closed-form-via-vector-space-of-infinite-sequences-of-real-numbers-and) that $1,0,1,0,1,0,...$ does not satisfy the recurrence

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Right. I have corrected the error.