# Fibonacci closed form via vector space of infinite sequences of real numbers and geometric sequences

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers, characteristic-polynomial

This question is from Linear Algebra with Applications (5th edition) by Otto Bretscher. It is in section 4.1 (Introduction to vector spaces), question 60. Below is the question:

> Consider the sequence $(f_0,f_1,f_2,...)$ recursively defined by
>   $f_0=0,f_1=1$, and $f_n=f_{n-2}+f_{n-1}$ for all $n=2,3,4,...$. This
>   is known as the *Fibonacci sequence*. In this exercise you are invited
>   to derive a *closed formula* for $f_n$, expressing $f_n$ in terms of
>   $n$, rather than recursively in terms of $f_{n-1}$ and $f_{n-2}$.
>
> 1. Find the terms $f_0,f_1,...,f_9,f_{10}$ of the Fibonacci sequence.
> 2. In the space $V$ of all infinite sequences of real numbers, consider the subset $W$ of all sequences $(x_0,x_1,x_2,...)$ that
>      satisfy the recursive equation $x_n=x_{n-2}+x_{n-1}$ for all
>      $n=2,3,4,...$. Note that the Fibonacci sequence belongs to $W$. Show
>      that $W$ is a subspace of $V$, and find a basis of $W$. Determine the
>      dimension of $W$.
> 3. Find all *geometric sequences* of the form $(1,r,r^2,...)$ in $W$. Can you form a basis of $W$ consisting of such sequences?
> 4. Write the Fibonacci sequences as a linear combination of geometric sequences. Use your answer to find a closed formula for $f_n$ (Binet's formula).
> 5. Explain why $f_n$ is the integer closest to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$, for all
>      $n=0,1,2,...$ Use technology to find $f_{50}$.
> 6. Find $\lim_{n \xrightarrow{} \infty} \frac{f_{n+1}}{f_n}$

For part 2. I found that the first terms of the sequence are $$(x_0,x_1,x_0+x_1,x_0+2x_1,2x_0+3x_1,3x_0+5x_1,5x_0+8x_1,8x_0+13x_1,...)$$
i.e. 
$$(1x_0,0,1x_0,1x_0,2x_0,3x_0,5x_0,8x_0,...)+(0,1x_1,1x_1,2x_1,3x_1,5x_1,8x_1,13x_1,...)$$
which led me to construct a basis
$$\mathfrak{B}=\{(1,0,1,1,2,3,5,8,...), (0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,...)\}=\{b_1,b_2\}$$
for $W$. So $W$ has dimension 2.

**My first question**: I am confused why the basis I found seems different from the basis found here: [Finding a Basis for the Vector space of sequences of the form $u_{n+1} = u _{n-1} + u_n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2985795/finding-a-basis-for-the-vector-space-of-sequences-of-the-form-u-n1-u-n-1)
which is $\mathfrak{C}=\{(1,0,1,0,1,0,...),(0,1,1,2,3,5,8,...)\}$. How could one get the first 4 terms, $(x_0,x_1,x_0+x_1,x_0+2x_1,...)$ with a linear combination of $\mathfrak{C}$?

For part 3., I noticed that the first 2 terms of such a geometric sequence will be $(1,r,...)$, which forces us to use weights 1 and r on $\mathfrak{B}$, yielding sequences of the form
\begin{aligned}
1b_1+rb_2 &= 1(1,0,1,1,2,3,5,8,...)+r(0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,...) \\
&= (1,r,1+r,1+2r,2+3r,3+5r,5+8r,8+13r,...)
\end{aligned}

So $r^2=1+r$, which has solutions $\phi_+=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\phi_-=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$. So all such geometric sequences in $W$ are of the form
$$(1,\phi_+,\phi_+^2, \phi_+^3, \phi_+^4 ...)$$
or
$$(1,\phi_-, \phi_-^2,\phi_-^3, \phi_-^4...)$$

They are 2 linearly independent vectors in $W$ (since neither is a linear combination of the other), and dim$W=2$, so they must span $W$, so together these form another basis for $W$.

For part 4., using the basis of geometric sequences we have
$$\alpha_1(1,\phi_+,...)+\alpha_2(1,\phi_-, ...)=(0,1,...)$$
so $\alpha_2=-\alpha_1$ and $\frac{\alpha_1+\alpha_1\sqrt{5}}{2}-\frac{\alpha_1-\alpha_1\sqrt{5}}{2}=1$, so the weights are $\alpha_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ and $\alpha_2=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$.

So 
$$f_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\phi_+^n - \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\phi_-^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\phi_+^n-\phi_-^n)$$

**My second question:** for part 5., how do we show $f_n$ is the integer closest to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\phi_+^n$? Is it because $\phi_-^n$ approaches 0 as $n \xrightarrow{} \infty$?

Also, what is the relationship between this method of finding the closed form of a recurrence and using characteristic polynomials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, I wouldn't put too much stock into the linked question, as $(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, \ldots)$ does not satisfy the recurrence relation (note: the 4th term is not the sum of the 2nd and 3rd). Your basis is correct.

For your second question, it is to do with $\phi_{-}^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, but it's more about how quickly it descends to $0$. All you really need is
$$\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\phi^n_{-}\right| < \frac{1}{2},$$
for $n \ge 0$, so that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\phi^n_{+}$ is never more than $\frac{1}{2}$ away from the $n$th Fibonacci number.
Since $|\phi_-| < 1$, the sequence $\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\phi^n_{-}\right|$ is decreasing, so it suffices to check the $n = 0$ case. When $n = 0$, this simplifies to the clearly true inequality
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} < \frac{1}{2},$$
so the desired inequality holds for all $n$.

Comment: A word of caution: while it is true, in theory, that the $n$th Fibonacci number can be calculated by rounding $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\phi_+^n$, for sufficiently large numbers, most computing systems will introduce an amount of error in the process of computing the $n$th power of $\phi_+$. There's no guarantee that the approximation of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\phi_+^n$ that your computer spits out will indeed be within $\frac{1}{2}$ of $f_n$.