# How to find a complementary subspace for the subspace of sequences where $u_{n+2}=u_{n} + u_{n+1}$, in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, lucas-numbers

Consider this subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ (sequences of real numbers):

$U = \{\vec{u} = (u_1, u_2, ...) \in \mathbb{R}^\infty | u_{i+2} = u_i + u_{i+1}$ for all $i\}$

My question is: **how can i find a *complementary* subspace $V$ of $U$?** Presumably it is infinite. If $V$ is complementary to $U$ in $\mathbb{R}$, I think $U \oplus V = \mathbb{R}^\infty$. But $\dim{U} = 2$ and $\dim{\mathbb{R}} = \infty$. So I think $\dim{V} = \infty$ as well.

Related: [Another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2985795/finding-a-basis-for-the-vector-space-of-sequences-of-the-form-u-n1-u-n-1) asked about finding a basis for this subspace. I think one answer is $\{\vec{x}, \vec{y}\}$ where $\vec{x}$ is the fibonacci sequence and $\vec{y}$ is the fibonacci prepended with $(1,)$. I.e., $\vec{x} = (0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, ...)$ and $\vec{y} = (1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, ...)$. Both of these are in $U$, are linearly independent, and I think span $U$ (but how to prove that is not immediately clear to me).

Given a basis of $U$, how should I proceed in constructing a complement to $U$?

Comment: If two vectors both belong to a two-dimensional subspace $U$ and neither one is a scalar multiple of the other, then they have to be a basis of $U$. Or do you mean you're not sure how to prove that $\dim U = 2$?

Comment: The latter; I'm trying to prove $\dim{U} = 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a lemma you might have seen in your lecture already: If $\varphi: V \to V$ is a linear projection with image $U$, then $W := \{v - \varphi(v) : v \in V\}$ is a complementary subspace of $U$. In other words, for every projection $\varphi : V \to V$, the images of $\varphi$ and $1-\varphi$ are complementary.

Find out how to prove this, then apply it to solve your original problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing that. So I have to construct a projection into $U$. If i have a sequence $v = (v_n)$, I can project it into $U$ (spanned by $\vec{x}, \vec{y}$) with $\phi(v) = v_1 \vec{x} + v_2 \vec{y}$. I think this would be a projection into $U$. That projection would seem to produce a $W$ complementary to $V$... e.g., for $w \in W$, $w_1 = w_2 = 0$. Is that a good way to proceed from your hint?

Comment: Indeed. Now that you found a complement, you technically don't even need to prove or use my hint in your solution, but I still recommend thinking about why it works.